# PutExtras with repeating alarmmanager

Tags: android, repeatingalarm

I want to schedule a repeating alarm at user define time. For that i am using following code

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            intent.putExtra("ontime", flag_ontime);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

All works fine...my alarm also fire at desired time but in my receiver i always get only default values from intent not passed one

AlarmReceiver.class

```
long id = intent.getLongExtra("id", -1);
 boolean ontime = intent.getBooleanExtra("ontime", false);
```

here id is always -1 and ontime is false....please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i for now i have solved this by using alarmmanager setExact() method and on each event fire i re-schedule alarm as per its repeating time....looking for batter solution